# AWS Clouwatch logs agent (awslogs) going crazy and writing GBs to log file

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I have had the problem several times on my production machine, it seems like for whatever reason, the [AWS log agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) gets desynchronized and starts writing like crazy to the log file the following error messages

```
2018-09-03 17:51:17,251 - cwlogs.push.reader - WARNING - 18880 - Thread-333 - Fall back to previous event time: {'timestamp': 1535992848000, 'start_position': 12956454L, 'end_position': 12956574L}, previousEventTime: 1535992848000, reason: timestamp could not be parsed from message.
2018-09-03 17:51:17,251 - cwlogs.push.reader - WARNING - 18880 - Thread-333 - Fall back to previous event time: {'timestamp': 1535992848000, 'start_position': 12956574L, 'end_position': 12956705L}, previousEventTime: 1535992848000, reason: timestamp could not be parsed from message.
```

... At the rythm of 10 per millisecond, so that's 10k log entries per second (ie ~36M lines of code in only one hour, given the line size this is no surprise I was getting several GBs of logs in only a few hours...

Anyone had the same issue and has some explaination / solution to counteract this bug ?

I don't know if this related yet, but some other error cause my DD to reach its inode cap, so I was probably getting a whole bunch of errors on many apps and processes relying on writing new files... would that be enough to turn the awslogs agent crazy ?

Comment: FYI, after upgrading to Amazon Linux 2 and using the newest awslogs via `sudo yum install -y awslogs
` this bug seems to have disappeared (or I have solved it doing other things, like  autoscaling, I'm not sure)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help, not sure, but I was seeing the same thing and realized it was likely due to java exceptions, sic multi-line entries that didn't match the timestamp in the config.  I added multi_line_start_pattern = {datetime_format} and that seems to have helped.  I found this link a pretty good resource for reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html

HTH,
JP